# Which Version of Matlab introduced isrow and iscolumn functions?

Tags: matlab

I have a script which uses the  [isrow](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/isrow.html) and [iscolumn](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/iscolumn.html) functions when called it generates the following error:

```
>> isrow( [1,2,3] )
??? Undefined function or method 'isrow' for input arguments of type 'double'.
```

What is the minimum version of Matlab I can use which will have these functions built in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`isrow(V)` and `iscolumn(V)` functions are available from **Matlab 2011a**.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code for `isrow()`

```
function Y = isrow(X)
%
% ISROW    True for row vectors.
%
%   Y = ISROW(X) returns logical 1 if X is a row vector, 0 otherwise.
%   ISROW returns 1 for scalars also.
%
%    See also: ISCOL.
%

if ndims(X)==2 & size(X,1)==1 & size(X,2)>=1
   Y = logical(1);
else
   Y = logical(0);
end
```

[Source via MATLAB Central](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/1309-general-extra-toolbox/content/isrow.m)