# Construct column vector with given values

Tags: matlab

i just started with matlab and stuck somewhere...consider example

```
X=(3:7)
Z=(2:6)
for (i=1:5)
    y=abs(X(i)-Z);

    dm=min(y);

    D=find(y==min(y))
    D1=Z(D);

end
```

i want D and D1 to be a column/row vector.Please help.

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you want your output to be? What will your vectors look like?

Comment: X =

     3     4     5     6     7


Z =

     2     3     4     5     6


D =

     2


D =

     3


D =

     4


D =

     5


D =

     5 ds is my output...but i am looking something like D=[2 3 4 5 5] or D=[2;3;4;5;5] or same output in some other variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you are storing scalar values into `D` and `D1`.
Maybe you wanted to save the values into i-th column of `D` and `D1`?

```
X=(3:7)
Z=(2:6)
for (i=1:5)
    y=abs(X(i)-Z);
    dm=min(y);
    D(i)=find(y==min(y));
    D1(i)=Z(D(i));
end
```

Comment: when i run the above code i get D as 5X5 matrix..i.e. the no of times the loop is running..1st row is [2 3 4 5 5] and this is also the 2nd, 3rd ,4th and 5th row..which i do not want. i simply want the output to be a 5x1 or 1X5 matrix (in this example).is this possible?? or to make another matrix which gives me the desired output??

Comment: The code above returns `D` and `D1` as 1x5 matrices, if they were not defined before.
Try to clear your workspace by `clear all` before running the code.

Comment: Please help me with ds also....a = dec2bin(rand(5,1)*100);
X = 3:7;
Z = 2:6;
for i = 1:5
    y    =  abs(X(i)-Z);
    dm   = min(y);
    D(i) = find(y==min(y));
end
D2 = D'
b  = a(D')
Output is

a =
01001
01110
10000
10011
11111

X =
 3     4     5     6     7

Z =
 2     3     4     5     6

D2 =
 2
 3
 4
 5
 5

b =
0
1
1
1
1
why it did not return

b = [01110
     10000
     10011
     11111]
How will i get this output?

Comment: b = a(D',:)
As `a` is a char matrix, you have to choose the whole rows.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to simply convert `D` and `D1` from row vectors to column vectors, you can simply add the following lines at the end of your code:

```
D = D';
D1 = D1';
```

The `'` operation simply gives you the transpose of the matrix in question.

Comment: `'` is conjugate transpose. To cover complex numbers one should use `.'` which is the transpose operator.

Comment: When i run the above code i do not get D or D1 as vectors...its like D=..., D=..., D=...., every time the loop runs...so how can i do D=D'??

Comment: @Misha: Just use `D=find(y==min(y)).'`

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
if isrow(D)
    D = D.'; % .' is the transpose operator
end
```

BTW: you don't need to use parentheses that often.

Comment: note that `isrow` [was introduced in R2011a](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14933237/which-version-of-matlab-introduced-isrow-and-iscolumn-functions) and cannot be used in older versions.

Answer (score 1):

I think the following will help too:

```
% convert ANY array into a column vector
D = D(:);

% convert ANY array into a row vector
D1 = D1(:).';
```

doing it like this will *guarantee* that one is column and the other row, without any performance loss.